# Woocommerce quantity increment with buttons not working after AJAX refresh and auto load only triggers after 2 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm really going crazy on this topic. Lots of people provided solutions but none is really working for me. My scenario might match with a lot of people:

I customized to WooCommerce quantity input (/global/quantity-input.php) and added to `<input>` to increase or decrease the amount in the quantity field:

```
<div class="quantity">
    <input class="step-btn minus" type="button" value="-">
    <input type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( 0 < $max_value ? $max_value : '' ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>" inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>" />
    <input class="step-btn plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

I use this jQuery loaded from my `functions.php`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('.quantity .step-btn.plus').on('click', function() {
         $input = $(this).prev('input.qty');
         var val = parseInt($input.val());
         var step = $input.attr('step');
         step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 1;
         $input.val( val + step ).change();
     });
     $('.quantity .step-btn.minus').on('click', function() {
         $input = $(this).next('input.qty');
         var val = parseInt($input.val());
         var step = $input.attr('step');
         step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 1;
         if (val > 1) {
             $input.val( val - step ).change();
         }
     });
});
```

On the cart page now I'm using this small jQuery snippet, also loaded from functions.php to auto-reload the AJAX after changing the quantity:

```
jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('click', '.qty, .plus, .minus', function(){
    jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty, .plus, .minus', function(){
    jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
});
```

**Now my Problems:**

1. The AJAX only reloads after clicking twice on `plus` or/and `minus`.
2. After the AJAX reloaded the buttons do not increase or decrease anymore.

Would be awesome to get some support here! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first Problem:

> The AJAX only reloads after clicking twice on `plus` or/and `minus`.

Problem here was, that I was trying to trigger the same object twice. It first executed the `disable` and then the refresh because I had two different jQuery functions for basically the same thing.

The second Problem is a general thing with JS and Ajax, it bassicly kills the the function. What worked for me is to reload on the `update_cart` action and reinitialize the function. See the entire code below, tested and working. I also added a small timeout to not `call` the AJAX with every click:

```
function enable_update_cart() {
    $('[name="update_cart"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}

function quantity_step_btn() {
    var timeoutPlus;
    $('.quantity .step-btn.plus').one().on('click', function() {
        $input = $(this).prev('input.qty');
        var val = parseInt($input.val());
        var step = $input.attr('step');
        step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 1;
        $input.val( val + step ).change();

        if( timeoutPlus != undefined ) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutPlus)
        }
        timeoutPlus = setTimeout(function(){
            $('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
        }, 1000);
    });

    var timeoutMinus;
    $('.quantity .step-btn.minus').one().on('click', function() {
        $input = $(this).next('input.qty');
        var val = parseInt($input.val());
        var step = $input.attr('step');
        step = 'undefined' !== typeof(step) ? parseInt(step) : 1;
        if (val > 1) {
            $input.val( val - step ).change();
        }

        if( timeoutMinus != undefined ) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutMinus)
        }
        timeoutMinus = setTimeout(function(){
            $('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
        }, 1000);
    });

    var timeoutInput;
    jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
        if( timeoutInput != undefined ) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutInput)
        }
        timeoutInput = setTimeout(function(){
            $('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
        }, 1000);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    enable_update_cart();
    quantity_step_btn();
});

jQuery( document ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function() {
    enable_update_cart();
    quantity_step_btn();
});
```

The `woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php` was not touched!

Enjoy